# System.InvalidOperationException: The type Database cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, wcf, nunit, assemblies, enterprise-library

I have been looking into refactoring some old code into a new WCF service, based on net 4.0 and have into a little difficulty with what should be a simple exercise!

The scenario;

WCF Service hosted over HTTP, implementing our ServiceContract, which connects to a local Sql Server.

When attempting to run a simple NUnit test against the Service Call, I get the following error;

> ***** HelpManager.Tests.GetPage.GetPageById Fault
>   Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   Database, key "HelpManagement" (Fault Detail is equal to An
>   ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation
>   error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key
>   "HelpManagement" ---->
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database", name =
>   "HelpManagement". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception
>   is: InvalidOperationException - The type Database cannot be
>   constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the
>   exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,HelpManagement 
>   ----> System.InvalidOperationException: The type Database cannot be
>   constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.GuardTypeIsNonPrimiti...).

Our (pretty standard) WCF web.config for this, looks like;

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true"/>
</configSections>

<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="HelpManagement"/>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HelpManagement" connectionString="server=(local);database=ieq;uid=;pwd=" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and an example of the code used to call it;

```
private const string DB_HelpManagement = "HelpManagement";
var db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(DB_HelpManagement);
```

Google et al have been no fun. I have checked versions etc and they all appear to be referencing the same 5.0.14 from GAC, so unsure as to what the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your nunit project have an app.config containing this configuration information, and the project references the patterns & practices DLLs?

Comment: @sfuqua. Yes it does (added to test), but why should I need it. As far as nunit is concerned, I am calling a WCF service, that service then calls the DB. Nunit should not need to have any knowledge of the inner workings of the service, just check the response.

Comment: Apparently I didn't get the intent - unit testing the service interface, not just the code _inside the service_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder about Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.dll and Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common -- are they referenced in the WCF project?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be your configuration.  Did you specify the dataConfiguration defaultDatabase value in your config file (e.g. [web.config](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/215290))?